# Trouble with Angular Resource query and MongoDB query operator

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb

I have problems with this bit in my app:

```
$scope.characters = Character.query({
    q: { 'user.id': user.id, 'status': { '$ne': 'deleted' } },
    f: { 'foo': 'bar' }
}, function() {
    // do something
});
```

Character is an Angular resource.

Angular strips the 'status' part during parsing, because the key '$ne' starts with a dollar sign, as documented here: http://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/docs/api/ng/function/angular.toJson

How can I get around that? Preferably without making changes to my backend (though as a last resort I can do a transform there, like say replacing pound signs with dollar signs in keys, before querying the Mongo database.)

Answer (score 0):

The query paramters are passed via URL (as you are doing a GET request). In order for this to work you should encode you 'unsafe' characters. For example, the dollar sign is not allowd in urls and should be encoded (see [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32417/dollar-sign-in-url-breaks-link)).

I would recommend you to encode your query parameters or, if you want to avoid this, try using a POST request (although that wouldn't be very restful).

For more information on how to encode your URI components, take a look at this MDN entry:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI

Comment: Angular Resource already encodes the parameters. First it calls toJson on them, stringifying them (and stripped out keys starting with $ - the problem), and the URLencoding them.